# Seaborn strippplot edgecolor doesn't change edgecolor

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have to plot my data as individual datapoints and use the colour scheme shown below (white background, blue hue based on the value on the x axis):
[image]

Generated from this code:

```
    ax = sns.stripplot(x = 'A', y = 'B', data = df, palette = my_palette, edgecolor = 'black')
    median_width = 0.4

    for tick, text in zip(ax.get_xticks(), ax.get_xticklabels()):
        sample_name = text.get_text()
        # calculate the median value for all replicates of either X or Y
        median_val = df[df[A] == float(sample_name)]['B'].median()
        # plot horizontal lines across the column, centered on the tick
        ax.plot([tick - median_width / 2, tick + median_width / 2], [median_val, median_val],
                lw = 1.5, color = 'k')
```

However, the data points at lower x values are almost indisinguishable from the white background. I've tried many variations of changing the edgecolor argument even using `plt.rc('patch', edgecolor = 'black')` but it doesn't work. How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to set the color of the edge lines, you also have to change their width, otherwise they are at 0 by default:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, edgecolor='k', linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I never would have thought of that. Thanks for providing a simpler solution than the one I found

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to access the x and y values for each data point. The following code gives me the plot I want:

```
x = []
y = []
for i in ax.collections:
    points = i.get_offsets()
    for pnt in points:
        x.append(pnt[0])
        y.append(pnt[1])
plt.scatter(x, y, facecolor = None, edgecolor = 'black')
```